# Javascript mp3 audio data

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, volume

Say i have a HTML5  tag. Is there any possible way for Javascript on the page to get the current speaker output, and then graph it to produce a volume bar that got larger when the music got louder and smaller when the music got quieter? I don't care if it works in IE or not. If this is not possible, would it be possible to extract that data out of the mp3 file and hope it lines up? I REALLY don't want to use flash.

Edit: I was inspired by [this](http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/waveform/). Unfortunately it uses hard-coded values which wont work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes it's possible.  Check out the esteemed [Mr. Doob's example](http://mrdoob.com/98/3D_Waveform).  Sadly, looks like the explanatory blog post is down.

Mozilla has a [custom extension](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API), but Doob's example is working in WebKit...

Comment: Mr. doob's example (my inspiration) uses hard-coded values :(. the mozzila extension does what I want, but I need at least support for webkit (I don't care about IE). Good job, it took you 8 minutes less to find the link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The JS Audio Data API will let you do this with an html5 audio tag, or audio that is played from javascript.  See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API for details and examples.  I don't know offhand what the status of this API is in current browsers.

Comment: It's Mozilla only, therefore works in Firefox only. WebKit also has an Audio API that's more complex but also allows you to achieve the same.